# How to concatenate columns properly using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a address in more than one column in a table.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, City, Country, PostalCode 
FROM Client
```

I am trying to concatenate address related columns into one filed using Comma (,) as a separator but if any of the column "eg. City" is null or empty, comma should not be there.

How to use ternary operator in TSQL like one has in c#?
Or suggest me the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you concatenate anything with a null, it returns null. So I'm trying to concatenate a comma with the given column value and if that expression returns null, I use Coalesce to return an empty string. At the end, if I get a value, the entire result will start with a comma. So I remove that comma using the Stuff function.

```
Select Stuff(
    Coalesce(',' + FirstName,'')
    + Coalesce(',' + LastName,'')
    + Coalesce(',' + StreetAddress,'')
    + Coalesce(',' + City,'')
    + Coalesce(',' + Country,'')
    + Coalesce(',' + PostalCode ,'')
    , 1, 1, '')
From Client
```

If you only want the address, then obviously you would only include those columns:

```
Select FirstName, LastName
    , Stuff(
        Coalesce(',' + StreetAddress,'')
        + Coalesce(',' + City,'')
        + Coalesce(',' + Country,'')
        + Coalesce(',' + PostalCode ,'')
    , 1, 1, '')
From Client
```

Comment: +1, again something learned :) But you should remove the first-/lastname from that because i think the OP only wants to concatenate the address.

Answer (score 29):

If you include the `NULLIF` function inside the `COALESCE` function it will work correctly for empty columns as well as `NULL` columns

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       STUFF(
           COALESCE(',' + NULLIF(StreetAddress, ''), '')  + 
           COALESCE(',' + NULLIF(City, ''), '') +
           COALESCE(',' + NULLIF(Country, ''), '') +
           COALESCE(',' + NULLIF(PostalCode , ''), ''),
           1, 1, '') AS "Address"
   FROM Client
```

Comment: NULLIF, cool!  Then you could add a LTRIM and RTRIM to remove any whitespace to get 
COALESCE(',' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(StreetAddress)), ''), '')

Answer (score 4):

Look at isnull

You can also look at using COALESCE function, please look it up in BOL:

> Returns the first nonnull expression
>   among its arguments.

Finally another thing you could do is use a CASE function.

```
SELECT Address1, CASE Address2 IS NOT NULL THEN "," + Address2 ELSE...
```

Comment: `SELECT City1 + ISNULL(City2)? "":","City2 ` is definitely not valid TSQL.

Comment: @Martin - Sorry that was SSIS.  But the rest should be valid.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question and SQL 2012 added the CONCAT function that made this sort of thing a bit easier. Try this:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, 
    Stuff(
        Concat(
        ',' + FirstName,
        ',' + LastName,
        ',' + StreetAddress,
        ',' + City,
        ',' + Country,
        ',' + PostalCode ),
    1,1,'')
From Client
```

CONCAT will automatically treat NULL as empty string so you dont need to use ISNULL or COALESCE. The STUFF function is there to remove the first comma, as in the answer by Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Case-Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
create table #Client(
FirstName varchar(20), 
LastName varchar(50), 
StreetAddress varchar(50), 
City varchar(20), 
Country varchar(20), 
PostalCode varchar(20)
)
insert into #Client(FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,City,Country,PostalCode)values('Jeff','Bridges','Street1','City1','US','12345')
insert into #Client(FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,City,Country,PostalCode)values('Steven','Baldwin','Street2','City2','US','12345')
insert into #Client(FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,City,Country,PostalCode)values('Barack','Obama','Street3',NULL,'US','12345')
insert into #Client(FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,City,Country,PostalCode)values('Nora','Jones','Street4','City4','US','12345')

SELECT FirstName, LastName,
(CASE WHEN City IS NULL AND StreetAddress IS NULL THEN '' 
      WHEN City IS Null AND StreetAddress IS NOT NULL Then StreetAddress 
      WHEN City IS NOT Null AND StreetAddress IS NOT NULL THEN StreetAddress + ',' + City END
)AS Adress, Country, PostalCode 
FROM #Client

drop table #Client
```

Comment: @Thanks. But adding all found columns (StreetAddress, City, Country, PostalCode) are really hard for me.. ?? How I gonna use this CASE statement?

Comment: @User: use [Thomas solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235391/how-to-concatenate-columns-properly-using-t-sql/5235783#5235783)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use ISNULL

```
Select FirstName, LastName
    , ISNULL(StreetAddress+', ','')
      +ISNULL(City+', ','')
      +ISNULL(Country+', ','')
      +ISNULL(PostalCode,'')
FROM Client
```

If a value is null, then the concatenation result will be null. ISNULL will replace the first expression with the second expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT_WS` is the function you want which will add together multiple columns with a specified separator. If any of the values are null they will not be included and nor will the separator.

Example:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', 'First', NULL, 'Third', 'Fourth');
```

Will return:

```
First, Third, Fourth
```

See more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql