# SQL Server controlling spaces when concatenating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

This seems a simple question, but it is something I always seem to be up against.

When concatenating two (or more) fields in SQL Server with adding a space between fields like:

```
SELECT Field1 + ' ' + Field2 FROM table
```

If `Field1` or `Field2` may be `null`, So we can use `ISNULL` to convert it to an empty string but the space remains. One way I have got around this is to add the space before checking if it is `null`. And then trimming the ends to allow for empty strings in the fields. E.g:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIIM(ISNULL(Field1 + ' ','') + ISNULL(Field2, ''))) FROM Table
```

This handles empty strings in either of the fields but gets very long if there is more than 2 fields to be concatenated in this way.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Field1 + ' ' + Field2, Field1, Field2, '')
FROM Table
```

This also avoid changes of `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` over fields.

---

But for more fields I use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ISNULL(' ' + Field1, '') + ISNULL(' ' + Field2, '')
                                    + ISNULL(' ' + Field3, '') 
                                    + ISNULL(' ' + Field4, '') 
                                    + ...
                                    + ISNULL(' ' + FieldN, ''), 2, 4000)
FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks @shA.t exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: With this approach, if Field1 is NOT NULL, the string will start in the 2nd characterd of Field1 which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I found [Aaron Bertrands answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11351622/685760) very helpful in doing something similar with a combination of NULLS and/or empty fields. For my solution, I ended up with;

```
SELECT STUFF(COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_line1)), ''), '') + 
          COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_line2)), ''), '') + 
          COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_line3)), ''), '') +
          COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_suburb)), ''), '') +
          COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_state)), ''), '') +
          COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.address_postcode)), ''), ''), 1, 1, '') 
          AS Address_Detail
```

This may well not be an "easier way", but it might help you with some alternative ideas.