# Need to concatenate 3 fields into one with carriage returns only when not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to combine 3 address line fields into one formatted address block field with carriage returns between the lines only if line 2 and line 3 are not null.

The code I have now is:

```
replace(ADDRESSBLOCK,' ','') =
        replace(coalesce(@ADDR2_1, '') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        coalesce(@ADDR2_2, '') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        coalesce(@ADDR2_3, ''),' ',''))
```

So for example if address line 1 equals 2014 Main St and address line 2 and 3 are null I get two extra carriage return lines in the result. I only want to conditionally have the carriage return lines if ADDR2 and/or ADDR3 are populated. Can anyone tell me how I might be able to do that in T-SQL?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate columns properly using T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235391/how-to-concatenate-columns-properly-using-t-sql)

Comment: Try a CASE statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL query:

```
SET addressblock = addr2_1
                    + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + addr2_2, '')
                    + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + addr2_3, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

`ISNULL` will return true if there is a `NULL` anywhere in the evaluated text parameter.

```
SELECT ISNULL( ADD1 , '') +
       ISNULL( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + ADD2 , '') + 
       ISNULL( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + ADD3  , '')
```

Comment: Slight nitpick, but it's not that NULL appears anywhere in the text parameter, it's that the evaluated text parameter is NULL because NULL concatenated (or added to, etc.) with any other value evaluates to NULL even if the other value is not NULL. I'm sure that's what you meant, but just want to make sure that's clear to other new users of SQL.

Comment: agreed, that's what i thought i stated, but thank you for clarifying.