# Concatenating Fields but not NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building some views to allow for one time data imports from another database. The source table has zero length strings (which I'll convert into `NULL` with `NULLIF`) but the address is causing me an issue.

Sample source table;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OriginalDataTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OriginalDataTable
GO
CREATE TABLE #OriginalDataTable (RowID int, Address1 varchar(20), Address2 varchar(20), Address3 varchar(20), City varchar(10), State varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #OriginalDataTable (RowID, Address1, Address2, Address3, City, State)
VALUES
 (1, '1 Wall Street','Downtown','','New York','NY')
,(2, '2 Floor Street','Uptown','','New York','NY')
,(3, '','','','','')
,(4, '3 Ceiling Street','','','New York','NY')
```

At the moment I'm leaning towards a CASE for each row but it doesn't seem very efficient. Can anybody suggest a better option for this?

```
SELECT
Address1 + ', ' + Address2 + ', ' + Address3 + ', ' + City + ', ' + State [Easy_But_Wrong]
,NULLIF(Address1 +
 CASE WHEN Address2 = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + Address2 END +
 CASE WHEN Address3 = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + Address3 END +
 CASE WHEN City = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + City END +
 CASE WHEN State = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' + State END ,'') [Using_CASE]
FROM #OriginalDataTable
```

It's got to be built into a view so that puts some methods out of the window.

This is my current output, I want it to look like the data on the right (notice the commas in the first column.

```
Easy_But_Wrong                                Using_CASE
1 Wall Street, Downtown, , New York, NY       1 Wall Street, Downtown, New York, NY
2 Floor Street, Uptown, , New York, NY        2 Floor Street, Uptown, New York, NY
, , , ,                                       NULL
3 Ceiling Street, , , New York, NY            3 Ceiling Street, New York, NY
```

Comment: "but the address is causing me an issue." what issue you are facing here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't want to show commas with no values between them. I'll update the question.

Comment: @RichBenner, you might combine your `NULLIF` approach with the `ISNULL/COALESCE` solutions acutally. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah, I've combined the approaches. I'll post as answer and link to the previously flagged duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235391/how-to-concatenate-columns-properly-using-t-sql).

I've combined that approach with `NULLIF` to get the desired output;

```
SELECT
    Stuff(
    Coalesce(',' + NULLIF(Address1,''),'')
    + Coalesce(',' + NULLIF(Address2,''),'')
    + Coalesce(',' + NULLIF(Address3,''),'')
    + Coalesce(',' + NULLIF(City,''),'')
    + Coalesce(',' + NULLIF(State,''),'')
    , 1, 1, '') [New_Address]
FROM #OriginalDataTable
```

Result;

```
New_Address
1 Wall Street,Downtown,New York,NY
2 Floor Street,Uptown,New York,NY
NULL
3 Ceiling Street,New York,NY
```